# Backup frequently a huge MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I have a huge MySQL InnoDB database (about 15 Go, and 100M rows), on a Debian server. 
I have to save my database every two hours in another server, but without affect performances.
I looked at the MySQL replication, but it does not correspond to the fact that I look for, because I also want to protect of problems which the application could possibly cause.

What would be the best way of dealing with it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you saying that the application can (and sometimes) creates faulty data?

Comment: Check out mysqlibinlog.  I'm not overly familiar with the process, but basically you can setup to use the replication logs to restore the DB.  So basically, you just periodically backup your logs and use them to rebuild the DB when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need incremental backups.

You can use Percona XtraBackup to make fast incremental backups.  This works only if your database uses only InnoDB tables.

Refer to the documentation about how to create incremental backups:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/howtos/recipes_ibkx_inc.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at writing a script that uses mysqldump to dump the contents of the DB, transfers it over to the backup DB (piping it to SSH would work), and inserts it via the command line?

There are options so that mysqldump won't lock the tables and so won't degrade performance too much.